# Retrieve data from a unstructured data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below data. It is derived from external file that is the reason the data is like this and it is a one time task.

```
Declare @Emp table(EmpId int,Division varchar(1),OfficerIsCertified int,EngineerIsCertified int,Officer Varchar(100),Engineer varchar(100),TeamLead Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @Emp
VALUES(1,'A',0,1,'Ram','Raj','Laxman')
,(2,'B',1,0,'Rajesh','Venki','Lokesh')
,(3,'C',1,1,'Sai','Suresh','Ramesh')
,(4,'D',0,0,'Kishore','Kiran','Kumar')
,(5,'E',1,0,'Venkatesh','Ravi','Raja')
```

I want the employees who are certified along with the their TL team.

Here 0 means 'Not Certified' and 1 is 'Certified'.

```
Division  EmpName     TL
A          Raj        Laxman
B          Rajesh     Lokesh
C          Sai        Ramesh
C          Suresh     Ramesh
E          Venkatesh  Raja
```

Could anyone please suggest the code to get the data as above.

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing unclear about this question (to those that have voted) but unpivoting is quite a simple task, what about the examples you've read didn't you understand?

Comment: Could you more explain. becouse your question is not clear,  we cant help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple unpivot followed by a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT E.Division,
       V.Name,
       E.TeamLead
FROM @Emp E
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(OfficerIsCertified,Officer),
                        (EngineerIsCertified,Engineer))V(IsCertified, [Name])
WHERE V.IsCertified = 1
ORDER BY E.Division;
```